# Добить программу, которая восстанавливает адрес и маску сети по данным во входном файле IP адресам

Tags: pascal, lazarus, delphi

Здравствуйте.

Можете проконсультировать по одной программе на Pascal? Алгоритм понятен, а с реализацией проблема. Программа почти написана, но отладить и добить по нормальному не получается.

Сейчас код нормально переводит все IP в двоичный вид. Но, там, где идёт сравнение битов, происходят странные вещи. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться из-за чего ошибки, что не так. Отловить некоторые ошибки не просто. Я пишу в Lazarus и стал косячить компилятор, много было странных багов (например, flag равен 0 и он нигде не устанавливается в единицу, а там есть условие if flag = 1 then break; и в этом месте при отладке прога зацикливалась, но ниже она ещё и выпадала с SIGSEGV  на выводе адреса). Переустановил Lazarus. Строковые переменные для хранения адреса и маски переделал в динамические массивы символов, тогда программа перестала падать на выводе адреса. Продолжили появляться SIGSEGV-ы, но с другими кодами и в других местах.

Ниже описаны алгоритм решения задачи, условие и приведён мой код.

**Вкратце:**

Нужно из входного файла прочитать IP адреса и по ним восстановить адрес и маску сети (наименьшей из возможных) и вывести в выходной файл.

**Подробнее:**

- Входной файл: ip.in
- Выходной файл: ip.out
- Ограничение по времени: 2 сек
- Ограничение по памяти: 64 Мб

***Условие:***

Каждый IP адрес это число состоящее из 4 байт записанных байт за байтом без пробелов в десятичном представлении с разделяющими точками byte0.byte1.byte2.byte3  Каждый байт записан как десятичное число от 0 до 255 (включительно) без ведущих нулей.

Сеть представлена двумя 4-хбайтными числами - адрес сети и маска сети. Оба числа записаны в том же представлении, что и IP адреса.

Для того, чтобы понять значение адреса и маски сети необходимо получить их двоичное представление. Двоичное представление IP адреса, адреса сети и маски сети состоит из 32 бит: 8 бит для нулевого байта (от более значимых к менее значимым), за которыми следуют 8 бит для 1-го байта, затем 8 бит для 2-го байта и 8 бит для 3-го байта.

Сеть состоит из из 2^n IP адресов, где 0 <= n <= 32. В маске всегда первые 32 - n бита равны 1, а остальные до конца  нули в двоичном виде. Первые 32 - n бита маски равны битам которые совпали у всех IP адресов, а остальные биты адреса сети до конца - нули. Сеть содержит все IP адреса, у которых первые 32 - n бита равны первым 32 - n битам сети адреса, а остальные биты произвольные. Одна сеть меньше другой, если она содержит меньшее количество IP адресов.

Например, сеть с адресом  194.85.160.176 и маской 255.255.255.248 содержит 8 IP адресов от 194.85.160.176 до 194.85.160.183 (включительно).

***Формат входного файла:***

Первая строка входного файла содержит единственное число m. Последующие m строк содержат IP адреса по одному адресу в каждой строке. Каждый IP может появиться во входном файле более одного раза.

***Формат выходного файла:***

Выходной файл должен содержать две строки, которые описывают наименьшую из возможных сеть содержащую все IP адреса из входного файла. Адрес сети должен быть в первой строке, а маска во второй строке.

***Ограничения:***

1 <= m <= 1000

**Пример.**

```
ip.in
3
194.85.160.177
194.85.160.183
194.85.160.178

ip.out
194.85.160.176
255.255.255.248
```

**Алгоритм.**

**1)** Получаем двоичное представление всех IP адресов из ip.in (рассмотрим на примере входных данных выше):

```
для 194.85.160.177:
1100001010101011010000010110001

для 194.85.160.183:
1100001010101011010000010110111

для 194.85.160.178:
1100001010101011010000010110010
```

**2)** Сопоставляем побитово все адреса. Все совпадающие биты переносим в адрес сети, параллельно, пока биты совпадают, в маску записываем единицы. С того индекса, где началось расхождение в битах IP адресов, в адрес и в маску до конца записываем все нули:

```
addr: 1100001010101011010000010110000
mask: 1111111111111111111111111111000
```

**3)** Преобразовываем адрес и маску обратно в десятичный вид и выводим в ip.out в представлении byte0.byte1.byte2.byte3:

```
194.85.160.176
255.255.255.248
```

**Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться из-за чего ошибки, что не так и реализовать второй и третий пункты алгоритма.**

***Код (Pascal):***

```
program ipnetwork;

//Переводит десятичное число в двоичное
function dec2bin(x:integer):string;
var s:string;
begin
  s:='';
  while x>0 do
  begin
     s:=chr(ord('0')+x mod 2)+s;
     x:=x div 2;
  end;
dec2bin:=s;
end;

var m, n, i, j, c, ind, flag: integer;
sbin, ip: array of string;
s, sint: string;
n_ip, n_mask: array of char;

begin
  assign(input, 'ip.in');
  assign(output, 'ip.out');
  reset(input);
  rewrite(output);

  readln(m);
  setlength(ip, m+1); // элементами массива будут строки с IP адресами
  setlength(sbin, m+1); // сюда запишем двоичное представление каждого IP

  s := '';
  sint := '';

  // Считываем
  for i := 1 to m do
  begin
      readln(ip[i]);
  end;

  // Перевод ip в двоичный вид
  for i := 1 to m do
   begin
      writeln(ip[i]); //Отладочная печать
      for j := 1 to length(ip[i]) do
       begin
            // Выделение чисел из IP:
            if ip[i, j] <> '.' then // если не точка
               s := s + ip[i, j] // пополняем число
            else
                //если точка, то заполненное число
                begin
                  val(s,n,c); // переводим в двоичный вид
                  s := '';
                  sbin[i] := sbin[i] + dec2bin(n); // и пополняем строку с двоичным представлением
                end;
       end;
      // Последний байт обрабатываем отдельно, т.к. числа четыре, а точки три
       val(s,n,c);
       s := '';
       sbin[i] := sbin[i] + dec2bin(n);
       writeln(sbin[i]); //Отладочная печать
       writeln;
   end;

  // Код ниже багает

  setlength(n_ip, 34);  // Массив символов для адреса сети
  setlength(n_mask, 34); // для маски сети
  i := 1;
  flag := 0;

  while i <= m do  // бежим по строкам
  begin
    if flag = 1 then // flag установится в 1, при первом несовпадении битов
       break;
    for j := 1 to 32 do // бежим по строкам
    begin
       if sbin[i, j] = sbin[i+1, j] then   // если биты совпали
           begin
              n_ip[j] := sbin[i, j]; // тогда в адрес сети кладём этот бит
              n_mask[j] := '1'; // в маску кладём 1
              inc(i);
           end
       else  // если биты не совпали
           begin
                ind := j; // запоминаем это место, чтобы с него залить всё нулями
                flag := 1; // чтобы сработало условие выхода из цикла
           end;
    end;
  end;

  // Заполняем адрес и маску нулями начиная с ind до конца
  for i := ind to 32 do
   begin
      n_ip[i] := '0';
      n_mask[i] := '0';
   end;

  // Отладочный вывод адреса и маски в двоичном представлении
  for i := 1 to 32 do
      write(n_ip[i]);
  writeln;
  for i := 1 to 32 do
      write(n_mask[i]);

  close(input);
  close(output);
end.
```

**Помогите, пожалуйста, реализовать второй и третий пункты алгоритма.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка здесь:

```
i := 1;
...
while i <= m do  // бежим по строкам
```

Нумерация элементов в массиве начинается с 0. Дальше не разбирался.

А вообще изначально подход неправильный. Нужно было адреса перевести в числа и работать с числами, они же хранятся в двоичном виде, и работать с ними операторами двоичной логики. Почитайте про операторы `AND`, `OR` и `NOT`.